# Can I use XAMPP's apache tomcat to execute java Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, xampp

I am using eclipse and I have a Dynamic Web Project .

To execute it I need apache tomcat 7.0.

But I have already installed XAMPP server that include both apache web server & apache tomcat server.

How can I mount my java web app to XAMPP's apache tomcat server?

Comment: Your Question : `Can I use XAMPP's apache tomcat to execute java Dynamic Web Project?` : I answered yes you can and I show you how ! Why you do not accept the answer ?

Comment: Any response from you ?

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 possibilities

**Option 1**

- You have two tomcat server running
- one inside eclipse and the XAMPP Tomcat
- you have to give the XAMPP Tomcat another port number
  here we give it a new port (8090) and redirectPort (8444).

..XAMPP\tomcat\conf\server.xml

---

original

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443" />
```

changed to

```
<Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8444" />
```

disadvantage you have to deploy the Web application 2 times

- 1 Eclipse deploy it to the eclipse Tomcat server
- 2 Manually deploy it to your XAMPP Tomcat server.
- 3 Manually start your XAMPP Tomcat server with
  `..XAMPP\catalina_start.bat`
- 4 Manually stop  your XAMPP Tomcat server with
  `..XAMPP\catalina_stop.bat`

here Tomcat runs on 8090

[image]

**Option 2** Change Eclipse settings.

- Windows -> Show View -> Servers
- In the servers view, right click and add new.
- It will show a pop up containing many server vendors.
- Under Apache select Tomcat v7.0 (Depending upon your downloaded server version).
- In the run time configuration point it to the XAMPP Tomcat folder (`....\XAMPP\tomcat`)

Advantage

- You need in XAMPP settings to change nothing.
- Eclipse deploy it for you.

Disadvantage

- on shutdown Eclipse, it will also stop XAMPP Tomcat server
- so you have to start and stop it manually with
- `..XAMPP\catalina_start.bat`

Comment: thank you it should work but i have always a problem with port running in my PC. i will check more. thank you again

Comment: @user3773380 : did you let your XAMPP Tomcat server ever run? It runs on 8080 so what for problem with ports ??

Comment: i make port 81 for XAMPP because in instalation it dosen't start. it tells me that port 80 is used despite i maked sure that skype is not running.

Comment: @user3773380 : not port 80 or 81 make port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

just start tomcat from ur Xampp Cpanel and put URL in browser localhost:8080, instead localhost, see [[below snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxf1q.png) and [below snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dPlA.png)

it will run http://localhost Apache , http://localhost:8080 tomcat